# How to use RegEx search modifiers in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, regex

How to activate and deactivate RegEx search modifiers using `Notepad++`? (`i`, `s`, `x`, `m`, `U`...)

Answer (score 2):

It works like in (almost) any regex flavour:

```
Activate  Deactivate
(?i:)      (?-i:)
(?s:)      (?-s:)
(?x:)      (?-x:)
(?m:)      (?-m:)
(?U:)      (?-U:)
```

You can combine them:

```
(?ixm:)    (?-ixm:)
.....
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use it just locally:

`(?i:[a-z])[a-z]`   would match Mx or mx but not MX , because the  'i' modifier (ignore case) only applies to what's inside the bracket, and after the colon.